# Using Ajax to display form data; returns [object FormData]

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, xmlhttprequest

I'm working on a larger Django app, but have made this page to test some functionality:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunc() {
            var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var data = document.getElementById("test");
            var fd = new FormData(data);

            xmlhttp.open("POST", "http://127.0.0.1:8000/test/", true);
            xmlhttp.send(fd);

            document.getElementById("text").innerHTML= fd;
        }   
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <br><br>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="test">
        <input type="button" onclick="myFunc()" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <p id="text">Submitted text goes here.<p>
</body>
</html>
```

I want whatever text that is put in the form to be displayed below. After hitting the submit button a) I get a HTTP 403 on the console, and b) the text is replaced with `[object FormData]`. I've tried some variations on `document.getElementById("text").innerHTML= fd;` (e.g. ...=fd.value;) but it doesn't work. Any thoughts?